# Bitwise Shifting Issue in C

Tags: c, bit-shift, disassembly

I have a 32-bit number and I want to create 4 pieces of 8-bit numbers from it. For example:

If the 32-bit number is `0xABCD1234`,
the 8-bit array must be like this:

`dataArray[0] = 0x34;
 dataArray[1] = 0x12;
 dataArray[2] = 0xCD;
 dataArray[3] = 0xAB;`

So I figured out that I can implement it by shifting the 32-bit value and masking the LSB part. Below snippet works well:

```
uint32_t uniquenumber = 0xABCD1234; 
uint8_t  dataArray[8];
int      j;
uint32_t  shifted = 0;

for(j=0;j<4;j++)
{
    shifted = (uniquenumber>>(j*8));
    dataArray[j] = shifted & (0xFF);
}
```

But if I try to shorten it by removing the `shifted` variable and transporting its calculation directly to the main calculation, it does not work. I couldn't figure out the difference, why does it not work. Here is the edited snippet which does not work.

```
uint32_t uniquenumber = 0xABCD1234; 
uint8_t  dataArray[8];
int      j;

for(j=0;j<4;j++)
{
    dataArray[j] = (uniquenumber>>(j*8)) & (0xFF);
}
```

The output of this second snippet is here:

`dataArray[0] = 0x34;
 dataArray[1] = 0x12;
 dataArray[2] = 0x00; //False.
 dataArray[3] = 0xAB;`

By the way, this is an embedded program working on a microcontroller. I don't think it is a printing issue because I'm not observing it by a printing operation. I'm observing it using a `Watch` in debug mode. Also, I can observe the first snippet at the same window and values are correct.

Update: Here are the dissamblies for both ways.

For first snippet:

[image]

And for the second snippet:

[image]

Compiler: ARM GCC 4.9-2015-q1-update

Debugger: Cypress PSoC Creator 3.3

MCU: CYBLE-022001

I will make a contact with Cypress, I guess they can give a hint about this. I will post the answer if we solve it.

Comment: [Both seem ok to me](http://ideone.com/TE1IO2). What is wrong in your second solution? What is the output?

Comment: What type is shifted?

Comment: I added the output of second snippet.

Comment: Code is alright. I am sure problem is somewhere else. You can try comparing the assembly generated for both versions.

Comment: @NejcGalof Sorry, I forgot to paste it here. It's `uint32_t`. Edited the question.

Comment: Maybe your printout is deferred after the posted code, and something else corrupt your array. try to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes @LPs show that works. Show your printout dataArray.

Comment: Edited the question, I'm not printing it but observing it at the debug mode.

Comment: Do you have any compiler optimization turned on? That's always the first thing I'm looking at, especially for embedded devices.

Comment: What does the dissembly look like?

Comment: Print in loop with this: `printf("0x%02X\n", dataArray[j]);` and then we see if you have problem in code or is problem in watch from debug mode.

Comment: I can not use `printf` as this is an embedded program :/ I tried disabling compiler optimization but that didn't work. I'm attaching assemblies to the post.

Comment: What compiler and debugger are you using for this code? What processor is it? Like Motorolla etc.?

Comment: @A.B. Edited the question for the compiler versions.

Comment: You realize that this is simply the little-endian representation?

Comment: Where did you put your breakpoint to stop the program and see the memory content?

Comment: @LPs Wow, I transported the breakpoint to 3 lines down and the value which was wrong just got true. I don't know why but I was already putting my breakpoint to a place where I'm sure that the for loop has been finished. It works well now. Thanks!

Comment: Optimisation is bad for debugging. Even `-Og` can be too much for stepping.

Comment: Bad to put an answer in the post.  Instead, revert post, add your own answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Thanks to @LPs,

I transported the breakpoint to 3 lines down and the value which was wrong just got true. I don't know why but I was already putting my breakpoint to a place where I'm sure that the for loop has been finished. It works well now.